# How to make this containers in flutter depending on length from api?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I try to make this column but data come form API, so i need solve to this problem ?**
[image]

Comment: use listview instead container and set listview property "shringwrap" = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `Listview` with `builder`

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          ProjectModel project = snapshot.data[index];
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Widget to display the list of project
            ],
          );
        },
      );
```

here `snapshot.data` is coming from future API for an example if your  API gives list of object you can use `FutureBuilder` to wait until request is complete. And fetch snapshot data to  `ListView.builder` here [docs about future builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) you can find clear idea from this